# Distance beetween lists in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python 3.4

I have many lists, like that:

```
A=[(1,2),(3,4),..]
...
N=[(10,2),(3,4),...]
```

I want to merge the lists, if exist minimum distance (between their points) < 10.

measure is `sqrt((x1-x2)^2+(y1-y2)^2)`

For example we have list with 3 matrix:

```
L= [A, B, C] 
A=[(1,2), (3,4)]
B=[(4,5), (100,1)]
C=[(1,2),(3,6)]
```

AFTER(we merger A and C because they are close):

```
L=[[(1,2),(3,4),(1,2),(3,6)],[(4,5),(100,1)]]
```

But how?

Many thanks.

Comment: how do you measure distance ?

Comment: Calculate distance, if less than 10 then merge. Easy.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do, or what part of it is beyond you. Give a [mcve] demonstrating the problem clearly.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at some form of [cluster analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis)